# Delete rows from data frame whose column entry overlaps with that of another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have two data frames with genomic data and I need to delete all rows in data frame 1 whose entry in the “feature” column is equal to an entry in the “feature” column in a row of data frame 2.

```
df1 <- data.frame(feature=c("ENSG419","ENSG1617","ENSG1629","ENSG16230"),distance=c(9833,2460,50538,51162),origin=c("e2","e2","e2","e2"))
df2 <- data.frame(feature=c("ENSG4939","ENSG1617","ENSG5844","ENSG10292"),distance=c(8441,8970,10320,139),origin=c("etoh","etoh","etoh","etoh"))

> df1
    feature distance origin
1   ENSG419     9833     e2
2  ENSG1617     2460     e2
3  ENSG1629    50538     e2
4 ENSG16230    51162     e2
> df2
    feature distance origin
1  ENSG4939     8441   etoh
2  ENSG1617     8970   etoh
3  ENSG5844    10320   etoh
4 ENSG10292      139   etoh
```

I would like to get this:

```
    feature distance origin
1   ENSG419     9833     e2
2  ENSG1629    50538     e2
3 ENSG16230    51162     e2
```

I tried to delete the duplicate entries by binding the two data frames to a new data frame and subsequently extracting the rows with identical features of the new data frame. Now I want to delete said rows from the original data frame 1.

```
df_new <- rbind(df1,df2)
df_new[duplicated(df_new[,1]),]
```

It didn’t quite work and I’m sure that there is a better solution, anyway. I’d be very thankful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df1[!df1$feature %in% df2$feature, ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would extract features from both, do a difference of the sets and then subset the first dataframe based on the results.

```
only1 <- setdiff(df1$feature, df2$feature)
df_sel <- df1[df1$feature %in% only1]
```

But I agree that Arun's solution is a oneliner :)

Comment: how do we expand it to all columns instead of just one